# Unable to Display Images from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to display images from MySQL. I've checked path etc. but still there are broken images on site. Below is my Code. Please guide me.

```
<div id="right_content">
    <div id="headline">
    <div id="headline_content"> <b>Welcome Guest!</b> <b style="color:#F56013">Shopping Cart</b> <span>-Items: -Price: </span> </div>
</div>
<div id="products_box">
    <?php
        $get_products ="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,6";

        $run_products = mysqli_query($con,$get_products);

        while($row_products=mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)){
            $prod_id = $row_products['product_ID'];
            $prod_title = $row_products['product_title'];
            $prod_cat = $row_products['category_ID'];
            $prod_brand = $row_products['brand_ID'];
            $prod_price = $row_products['product_price'];
            $prod_desc = $row_products['product_desc'];
            $prod_img =$row_products['product_img1'];



            echo "
            <div id='single_product'>
            <h3>$prod_title</h3>
            <img src='admin_area/product_images/$prod_img' width='180' height='180' />
            </div>
            ";
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, view your HTML source.  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: are you saving the images inside the DB? or just the name of the file?

Comment: i am saving names. Problem is solved. The images were not moving into the directory and i didn't check that. When i manually copied them into the specified directory the problem was gone. 
Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment, problem is solved. The images were not moving into the directory and i didn't check that. When i manually copied them into the specified directory the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

When you write html please note that you should always use double and not single quotes for tag properties. So for example

```
src='admin_area/product_images/$prod_img'
```

should be

```
src="admin_area/product_images/$prod_img"
```

and so on. Since you are doing echo using double quotes you should escape double quotes with .
So your echo should look like:

```
echo "
    <div id=\"single_product\">
    <h3>$prod_title</h3>
    <img src=\"admin_area/product_images/$prod_img\" width=\"180\" height=\"180\" />
    </div>
";
```

IMHO it is better to write plain html and use php only to echo variables just to avoid this kind of problems with the generated code. So I'd write:

```
?>
        <div id="single_product">
        <h3><?php echo $prod_title; ?></h3>
        <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $prod_img; ?>" width=\"180\" height=\"180\" />
        </div>

<?php } ?>
```

This will save you a lot of headache in case of debugging if your code is not working